# Python keeps returning blank list when trying to append?

Tags: python, for-loop, append

brand new to python and trying to learn for loops. Trying to take the values from two lists to calculate BMI of each person but keep getting a blank list.

```
heights = [184, 177, 190, 188, 159, 166]

weights = [84.9, 81.8, 86.1, 92.2, 69.6, 72.0 ]

BMIS = []

for i, bmi in BMIS:

  BMIS.append(weights[i] / heights[i])

print(BMIS)
```

Comment: Too obvious, `BMIS` is an empty list. the iteration will occur 0 time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through an empty list. Just use `zip` to loop through each list at once.

```
for height, weight in zip(heights, weights):
    BMIS.append(weight / height)
```

This comprehension will result in the same list:

```
BMIS = [weight/height for height, weight in zip(heights, weights)]
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This is first time seeing the zip function. Great help!!

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through BMIS it's an empty list .loop through hights or weights

```
heights = [184, 177, 190, 188, 159, 166]
weights = [84.9, 81.8, 86.1, 92.2, 69.6, 72.0 ]
BMIS = []
for i in range(len(heights)):
    BMIS.append(weights[i] / heights[i])
 print(BMIS)
```

Comment: Never realized and I've been looking at this for hours now lol. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is in the list that you are trying to loop over.  The code in the body of the for loop will never be executed.  You can change your for loop to:

```
for height, weight in zip(heights, weights):
    BMIS.append(weight/height)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that heights an weights list have always the same len(), you can loop using it as your range

```
heights = [184, 177, 190, 188, 159, 166]

weights = [84.9, 81.8, 86.1, 92.2, 69.6, 72.0 ]

BMIS = []

for i in range(len(heights)):

  BMIS.append(weights[i] / heights[i])

print(BMIS)
```

Comment: Thanks so Much! Didn't think I could use len function like that, worked great!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverFlow. Let's check your main for loop:

```
for i, bmi in BMIS:

  BMIS.append(weights[i] / heights[i])
```

Since you are initializing `BMIS = []` you're iterating over an empty list. A better approach is to iterate in a range like so:

```
for i in range(0, len(heights)):
    BMIS.append(weights[i] / heights[i])
```

This way you're accesing the ith position of each list, doing the division and appending the result to your `BMIS` list.